# Where to place a default value to return from a Model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, models

I have a model called City.

I have several methods that look for a City depending on different attribute (city close to zip code, city by population...etc).  However, if a city is not found I want to default to a given city, let's say New York.

So I have found myself doing this a lot:

```
@city = City.find_by_zip_code(83030)
if @city.nil?
 @city = City.find_by_name('New York')
end
```

This is just in a method where I look by zip code, but I keep doing this in several methods.  Where and how should I centralize this default:

```
City.find_by_name('New York')
```

EDIT:

Would it be a good idea to have a method like this:

```
def self.default_city
 @default_city = City.find_by_name('New York')
end
```

To avoid fetch the database everytime I want to get the default city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least make it easier to type out:

```
@city = City.find_by_zip_code(83030) || City.find_by_name('New York')
```

To avoid extra db hits, cache the default:

```
def self.default_city
  Rails.cache.fetch('default_city') do
    City.find_by_name('New York')
  end
end
```

I have a blog post with a few more details about caching like that:
http://www.tmatthew.net/blog/rails-caching-example

Comment: Is there any difference between your Rails.cache, and doing @default_city ||= City.find_by_name('New York') ?

Comment: Yes. The cache will last for as long or short as you want it to (:expires_in option). Using an instance variable still requires that you run the query on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Look for find_or_initialize_by_ in ActiveRecord::Base

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: That method really isn't what he's asking for.